# Javascript: Conditional count time on web pages and broadcast custom event

Tags: javascript, time, conditional-statements, cout

I have following custom use case need to solve in **pure JavaScript client side only**

Calculate total time spent by user in current user session on **certain group of pages** from website. If time spent reaches to **certain timelimit**, broadcast event to notify.

Here calculation is conditional based on maxTime limit and URL path that matches some group of pages.

[www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com) is site and if user visit  all pages under 
abc.com/B/ 
or
abc.com/x/a.html 
or 
abc.com/y/b.html , calculate time  
and it time is **15 second** broadcast to all and reset.

Use may visit diff. pages in same session where on some pages time need to keep adding and some page do not count and once user come back to specific pages ,continue time counting.

So trying to see how to capture page URL conditions and use in logic to calculate time on specific group of pages & site is mix of SPA (soft navigation) pages and classic pages and when to start and puase counting.

```
var startTiming=new TimeMeasure([‘www.abc.com/b/*’,”www.ac.com/x/a.html”],15)
```

Here high level of my class design  to explain what i m tring to do

```
var TimeMeasure = (function() {
    function TimeMeasure(path, maxTimeMS) {
        this.start = 0; //can be private
        this.end = 0; //can be private
        this.duration = 0; //can be private
        this.pagePath = path||['*']; //array of string which contains diff regx or url pattern?
        this.maxTime = maxTimeMS;
    }
    TimeMeasure.prototype = (function() {
        function startFn() {
            //TODO: check if current URL match with location path
            this.start = new Date();
        }

        function updatetimeCalc() {
            //TBD how check if current URL match with location path
 this.end =new Date();
            this.duration += (this.end.getTime() - this.start.getTime());
            //save in cookie or storage
            window.sessionStorage.setItem("timeongropofpage");
          //can this.start=this.end ??
            this.notifyIfMaxtimespent();
        }

        function awayFn() {
            updatetimeCalc.call(this);
        }

        function unloadPage() {
            updatetimeCalc.call(this);
        }
        return {
            "init": function() {
                this.start = 0;//or new Date()
                this.end = 0;
                this.duration = window.sessionStorage.getItem("timeongropofpage") || 0;
                window.addEventListener('focus', startFn.bind(this));
                window.addEventListener('blur', awayFn.bind(this));
                window.addEventListener('beforeunload', unloadPage.bind(this));
//should click event also to consider to keep
                //document.body.addEventListener('click', updatetimeCalc.bind(this)); 
                //does blur and unload both call when page is unloading?
                // on mobile browser befreunload call?
               setTimeout(function(){  updatetimeCalc.call(this) }.bind(this), this.maxTime);
                
            },
            "reset": function() {
                this.start = 0;
                this.end = 0;
                this.duration = 0;
                //reset storage or cookie

            },
            "notifyIfMaxtimespent": function() {
                if (this.duration >= this.maxTime) {
                    var event = new CustomEvent("userSpentTime", {
                        detail: {
                            timeSpent: true
                        }
                    });
                    //broadcast to all
                    window.dispatchEvent(event);
                    //rest all 
                    //this.reset()
                }
            }
        };

    })();
    return TimeMeasure;
}());
```